# python - issue in looping and compare logic

Tags: python, loops

I am having an issue in my python looping logic. I read in an input file that looks like this:

[image: vowel input file]

and my expected output is this. I need to match all input with the exact same vowels. The order doesn't matter

[image: Expected Output]

What I am getting is this:

[image: Actual output]

Here is the code for my for loop:

```
  #split line into key and value
  next_key_found, value = line.split('\t')
 
  #sort key alphabetically
  next_key_found = sorted(next_key_found)
  next_key_found = ''.join(next_key_found)
  
  # If current key  = next key add 1 tot vowel total
  if current_key_being_processed == next_key_found:
        vowel_total = vowel_total + int(1)

  # trying to account for key being a space here     
  if current_key_being_processed != next_key_found:
       vowel_total = 0   
       if next_key_found is not None:
             current_key_being_processed = next_key_found
             vowel_total = vowel_total + int(1)             
  else:
       # if key change add key. Add vowel total to dict. Zero out total and set current to next             
       if current_key_being_processed:
           current_key_being_processed = ''.join(sorted(current_key_being_processed))            
           vowel_dict[current_key_being_processed] = vowel_total
           vowel_total = 0 
           current_key_being_processed = next_key_found
```

I am trying to figure out where in my logic I am going wrong.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample data instead of posting image.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Remove the `input` process; hard-code your test case.  Note that your posted code does not run, due to undefined symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code could be simplified by just processing all the lines first and then outputting the resultant sums for each sorted string:

```py
lines = [
         ' \t1',
         ' \t1',
         'eoe\t1',
         'oe\t1',
         'oe\t1',
         'ooe\t1'
         ]

counts = {}

for line in lines:
    key, value = line.split('\t')
    key = ''.join(sorted(key))
    counts[key] = counts.get(key, 0) + int(value)
    
for key, value in counts.items():
    print(f'{key}\t{value}')
```

Output:

```
    2
eeo 1
eo  2
eoo 1
```

Comment: I think that will work how would I do it reading an input file in from command line - would I do something like this for line:  for lines in sys.stdin:

Comment: @JimRyan you'd loop exactly the same way as you currently are (you say the code you posted is for "my for loop", so just leave the `for` part at the beginning of the loop as is.